# How to loop an object and push key value into a key-value object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

I dont know, how to loop an object and push his key and value into a key-value object. 
now I give you an example.

input object looks like this:

```
{a: 1, b:2, c:3}
```

and the output object array should be look like this:

```
[{key: a, value: 1}{key: b, value 2} {key: c, value: 3}]
```

any solutions?

Comment: There's a built-in function for that, it's called `Object.entries`

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use `Object.entries` method:

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v])=> ({key: k, value: v}));
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v])=> ({key: k, value: v}));
console.log(result);
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable string-keyed property `[key, value]` pairs, in the same
>   order as that provided by a `for...in` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
new Map(Object.entries({a: 1, b:2, c:3}));
```

Answer (score 0):

A short method

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value])=> ({key, value}));
```